# Get xml2 to read output of another command as a file and not an assigned name?

Tags: bash, loops, xml-parsing, xml2

In a script I am running a cURL command that returns a xml file. I am trying to take the result of the cURL command and parse it with xml2.

```
#! /bin/bash
# xmlParse.sh

while read line
do
   appID=`echo $line 
         | awk -F "app_id=" '{print $2}' 
         | awk '{print $1}' 
         | sed 's/\"//g'`

     # output is a numerical value, ex: 123456

   scanID=`curl --silent -u $uid:$pw $second_api_call -F app_id="$appID" 
          | awk -F "scan_id=" '{print $2}'
          | awk '{print $1}'          
          | sed 's/\"//g' 
          | sed '/^$/d' 
          | tail -1` # this grabs the last scan on the app.

    # output is a different numerical value, ex: 1234567

   get_report=`curl --silent -u $uid:$pw $last_api_call -F scan_id="$scanID"`

    # $get_report output is a report in a single line xml file.

   c_name=`"xml2 < $get_report" | grep @name= | cut -d "=" -f2`

   echo $c_name

done < <(curl --silent -u $uid:$pw $first_api_call)
```

My error looks like:

```
./xmlParse.sh: line 7: xml2 < <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>......
xml: File name too long
```

It seems like it isn't reading as a .xml file, but as the whole file is a name. The xml file does return as one line. I have tried multiple possible solutions, but feel like I am just digging myself a deeper hole and running in circles now. When I run the commands in terminal, it works fine and returns results looking like:

```
$ xml2 < report.xml | grep @name= | cut -d "=" -f2
Data Issues
Insufficient Memory
Insufficient Memory
Insufficient Memory
RSA Algorithm 
Risky Algorithm
Code Quality
Improper Execution
Wrong Operator in String
Sensitive Information
Exposure Through Sent Data
```

Comment: It seems to me more logical to execute in a body of a cycle not `curl --silent -u $uid:$pw $last_api_call` but `get_report="$line"`. Because at you it turns out that you twice fulfill request `curl`, and on logic should use the current line of the request forming a cycle

Comment: Ya, I'm sorry. It was a poor example. There are actually 3 different api calls to get the report I want. That's why I tried to say $first_api_call vs $last_api_call.

Comment: @AndreyKarpov The `$first_api_call` gets me an application name, a `$second_api_call` takes the result of the `$first_api_call` and gets the scan id, so the `$get_report` (3rd api call) takes the scan id results from $second_api_call and calls for the full xml report. From there is where I implement the code I left above: `c_name=`"xml2 < $get_report" | grep @name= | cut -d "=" -f2``.

Comment: can you show the output of string for what this pipe `awk -F "scan_id=" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed '/^$/d' | tail -1` and show me what do you want to get from this

Comment: The output to scanID is just a numerical factor like `366302`

Comment: @AndreyKarpov I get a full report in the `$get_report`, but it seems different implementing it with `xml2` compared to just needing to search for 1 value. Some of the reports are very large, and some reports may have null values